# Youtube Player API is slower than website load

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have a website which has an index page with a lot of text and a button that triggers a modal window, in which you may see a YouTube video. In a normal scenario (people reads the text of the page, then realize the button, they click the button) there's no problem, but when I click the button just after my page loads (or during...) the modal window appears but no video in it, of course FireBug throws an error saying that the video isn't loaded yet.

I don't mind waiting the video to load after pressing the button, I'd like to push the button and 100% of the times watch the video, but I don't know how to start loading the Api in the moment I want. There you have some relevant pieces of code:

```
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player("player", {
        height: $('#modalvideo').height()*0.9,
        width: $('#modalvideo').width()*0.9,
        videoId: "NeeTGjp5-Ag"
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".youtube").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE I WOULD WANT TO LOAD THE YOUTUBE API, EVEN IF I HAVE TO WAIT
        $("#modalvideo").modal("show");
        player.playVideo();
    });
});
```

Thank you everybody!

Comment: Can't you just move `$("#modalvideo").modal("show");` and `player.playVideo();` to `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`?

Comment: Not really @ahwayakchih, I don't want to play the video when it's ready. What I want is to start loading the API and play the video whenever I push the button.

Comment: Ah, ok then. I've added answer with one of possible solutions.

Comment: Updated my answer with working jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe (sorry it does not seem to work inside stackoverflow's snippet iframe - you can try working jsfiddle instead: https://jsfiddle.net/hzmdj2m6/)?

```js
var player;
var playWhenReady = false;

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  console.log('API is ready');
  player = new YT.Player("player", {
    height: $('#modalvideo').height() * 0.9,
    width: $('#modalvideo').width() * 0.9,
    videoId: "NeeTGjp5-Ag",
    playerVars: {
      origin: 'http://stacksnippets.net'
    },
    events: {
      onReady: onYouTubePlayerReady
    }
  })
}

function onYouTubePlayerReady(e) {
  console.log('Player is ready');
  player.isReady = true;
  if (playWhenReady) {
    playVideo();
  }
}

function playVideo() {
  console.log('playVideo');
  if (player && player.playVideo) {
    console.log('now');
    //$("#modalvideo").modal("show");
    player.playVideo();
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('postpone');
    playWhenReady = true;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".youtube").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    playVideo();
  });
});
```

```css
#modalvideo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="youtube">play</a>
<div id="modalvideo">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
```

Or use queueing: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Queueing_Functions

Comment: It worked!! thank you very much!! is a very smart idea to add those flags about whether I'm ready to play or not.